# Swift Convert string Base64 to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64

I'm trying to convert base 64 encoded string to `UIImage` with the following code:

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String!, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0) )

print(decodedData) //I get data here (It is not nil)

var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) //return nil
```

The `decodedData` seems fine, Why do I get `nil` when converting to `UIImage`?

Comment: I had a mistake with my question:

Comment: If decodedData != nil but decodedimage == nil then the data is not in a valid image format.

Comment: Hi, you right! It was extra characters at the beginning of the base64 string. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try to pass no options, I also recommend using unwrap for optionals :

```
if let string = base64String {
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String!, options: []) 
    if let data = decodedData {
        var decodedimage = UIImage(data: data)
    } else {
        print("error with decodedData")
    }
} else {
    print("error with base64String")
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. The program doesn't print any of 2 prints in code. It means that the data is not nil. For some reason, the code refuse to convert the 'data' to UIImage and return nil in that step.

Comment: could be a problem with the data you retrieve

Comment: Yes, you right. As I mentioned above, I got several characters at the beginning of the Base64 string. After I removed it, the data could be converted to UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 4.2**

```
if base64String != nil {
        let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: base64String!, options: [])
        if let data = decodedData {
            let decodedimage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
            cell.logo.image = decodedimage
        } else {
            print("error with decodedData")
        }
    } else {
        print("error with base64String")
    }
```